# Scroll to element without using JQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to scroll the page so a specific input that is in a area outside the landing screen can be visible. Something like this :

```
document.getElementById('my-input').scrollTo();
```

All examples i've seen in SO uses JQuery, but i want to do it with pure JS... How can i ?

Thanks !

Comment: [The `.scrollIntoView` API isn't standard but it's widely supported.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) Of course, that's not "pure JS" either because it's a browser API and not part of the language.

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) (scrollTo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the non standardized (but well supported) [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method:

```js
document.getElementById('bar').scrollIntoView();
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 5000px;
  background: red;
}

#bar {
  height: 1000px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Or you can use [`scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo), taking the element's top as y coordinate.

```js
window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('bar').getBoundingClientRect().top);
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 5000px;
  background: red;
}

#bar {
  height: 1000px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Comment: @Marie no problem. It was the first time I've heard about that, so it was still interesting to read about it... :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `anchors` to scroll to a specific `ID` if that helps you in any single way.

---

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<a href="#b">Press Me</a>
<br><br>
<div id="a">
A
</div>

<div id="b">
B
</div>

<div id="c">
C
</div>

<div id="d">
D
</div>
```